# Как добавить класс всем элементам со значением data-атрибута равным значению data-атрибута выбранного элемента?

Tags: javascript

Имеются элементы с data-атрибутами.
[image: Элементы]

Пытаюсь реализовать следующее:
При клике на элемент определяется значение его data-атрибута. Оно сравнивается со значениями data-атрибута остальных элементов. При равном значении этим элементам добавляется класс.
[image: код]

Но такой код не работает:
[image: результ]

Подскажите, как это можно реализовать. Я только учусь и понимаю, что скорее всего делаю неправильно.

Comment: у вас в условии clicked.stars (dataset забыли) -> clicked.dataset.stars

Comment: вот балда! спасибо!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы реализовал это следующим образом:

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

cards.forEach(card => {
  card.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const dataCard = card.dataset.card;

    cards.forEach(item => item.classList.remove("selected"));

    [...cards].filter(item => item.dataset.card === dataCard).map(item => item.classList.add("selected"));
  });
});
```

```css
.cards {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 12px;
}

.selected {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card" data-card="1">Data 1</div>
  <div class="card" data-card="1">Data 1</div>
  <div class="card" data-card="2">Data 2</div>
  <div class="card" data-card="1">Data 1</div>
  <div class="card" data-card="2">Data 2</div>
  <div class="card" data-card="1">Data 1</div>
  <div class="card" data-card="1">Data 1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Плохо знаю методы перебора массива)

Подскажите, а как можно сделать вместо добавления класса - удалить все элементы, у которых значение data-аттрибута не равно элементу события?

Comment: @horoshere вам точно нужен такой результат? Имею ввиду, что в данном случае будут выделены все, если нажать на разные элементы. Я думал вы хотели, чтобы при нажатии на другой элемент пропадали пометки предыдущих и выставлялись на новые

Comment: @horoshere На счёт вопроса, а потом при повторном нажатии чтобы вернулись все остальные элементы?

Comment: @EzioMercer да, вы правы. Я бы хотел чтобы при нажатии на другой элемент пропадали пометки предыдущих. Но это промежуточный результат. В конечном итоге пытаюсь получить чтобы при нажатии на элемент оставались, в данном случае, команды с таким же data-status как у выбранного, а остальные удалялись.

Comment: @horoshere Понятно, а как потом выбрать другие? Повторно надо нажать на один из оставшихся, чтобы пропал выбор и показались все?

Comment: @horoshere, поправил ответ

Comment: @EzioMercer суть в том, чтобы из оставшихся выбрать еще одну команду. Таким образом, останутся 2 команды с равнозначным data-status) А потом уже да, сброс и заново.

Comment: @Alexandr_Yakovlev здорово! Только тут видимо должно быть так :) const dataCard = card.dataset.stars; (в конце stars)

Comment: @horoshere, да, все верно